# How to run bash commands like "npm install" on complie

Tags: yesod

I need to run `npm install && gulp build` inside my `static/semantic-ui` folder, so it creates the needed `css` file.

I saw this example with [Setup.hs](https://github.com/nakaji-dayo/yesod-job-queue/blob/6912232acc0b08d712d394c4f816d11f76786a60/Setup.hs#L13), however on my scaffolded project I don't have it, so my question where is the right place to put the code to run those bash commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the default Yesod scaffolding (generated by `stack` tool), then it indeed doesn't contain `Setup.hs` (which is a bit weird, as their own guide - https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/GUIDE.md - recommends having it as a good practice)

`Setup.hs` should be located in main project directory (same where `stack.yml` and `yourproject.cabal` are located) and content should be roughly the same as in your included example (`defaultMainWithHooks` is the key part).

Details of hooks usage are specified in https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html and in `cabal` spec: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-1.24.0.0/docs/Distribution-Simple.html

BTW, for now `stack` doesn't support pre-build hooks on its own (for details see: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/503), so you have to stick to ones provided by `cabal` - that's where `Setup.hs` comes from.