# When building a Haskell project using Stack, can I specify a custom pre-build step?

Tags: haskell, build, haskell-stack

Some Haskell packages require a custom pre-build step before any invocation of GHC. For example, the [unix package](https://github.com/haskell/unix) requires an invocation of `autoreconf -i` before its C bindings can be compiled.

Let's say I want to "stackify" such a package. Is there any way to specify within `stack.yaml` that `autoreconf -i` should be called first, as a pre-build step?

Currently, (assuming I add a basic `stack.yaml` to `unix`), I must perform the following steps in order to build:

```
autoreconf -i
stack build
```

Is it possible to reduce this down to just a single step? As in:

```
stack build
```

Comment: As far as I know, right now you have to use Cabal's infrastructure for that. Related ticket: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/503

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using standard Cabal infrastructure (as mentioned by @Sibi) -  you will need `Setup.hs` file in your main project directory. Seems that a similar question was already asked here: [How to run bash commands like "npm install" on complie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38903177/how-to-run-bash-commands-like-npm-install-on-complie/39078496#39078496)